# Safari Auto-Extract ZIP File Upon Download

Tags: safari, macos

When I download a zip file through Safari it automatically extracts it into a new folder named as the ZIP file is.  Is there a way to disable the auto extract feature and just leave the file as is in ZIP format?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Safari go to Preferences -> General and uncheck `Open "safe" files after downloading`. This disables automatic extracting of archives, including zip files. As noted below the check box this will disable automatic opening of PDFs, text documents, movies and pictures.

Comment: Or, to have both (open PDFs/texts/movies/pictures but don't extract ZIP), disable auto-open in Safari but attach an AppleScript FolderAction to your Downloads folder which checks whether the file is a ZIP file, and if it's not, opens it. This also has the advantage that it will work with any browser.

Answer (score 5):

You can also hold the ALT (OPTION) key when clicking the download link  (tested and working on Safari v6.0.5)

Comment: Really this should be the accepted answer, since it does exactly what the OP is looking for.  (and what I was looking for too : )